# Merge data frames on columns that has slightly different values in each data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge to data frames based on the column containing names of teams.

While the names of teams are correctly written in one of the data frames ('New England Patriots', 'New York Giants'...), in the second data frame the names are messed up and all I know is that the last word of the team name is still last ('zapjizaPatriots', 'qdsjbGiants'..).
I've been trying to figure out a way to somehow use regex and `pd.merge` simultaneously but nothing's working.

```
df1 : {'team': {1: 'New England Patriots', 2: 'Miami Dolphins', 3: 'Buffalo Bills', 4: 'New York Jets', 6: 'Baltimore Ravens'}, 'W': {1: 11, 2: 7, 3: 6, 4: 4, 6: 10}, 'L': {1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 10, 4: 12, 6: 6}, 'Ratio': {1: 2.2, 2: 0.7777777777777778, 3: 0.6, 4: 0.3333333333333333, 6: 1.6666666666666667}} 

df2 : {'Metropolitan area': {0: 'New York City', 1: 'Los Angeles', 2: 'San Francisco Bay Area', 3: 'Chicago', 4: 'Dallas–Fort Worth'}, 'NFL': {0: 'GiantsJets', 1: 'RamsChargers', 2: '49ersRaiders', 3: 'Bears', 4: 'Cowboys'}}
```

Comment: how large is your 1st and 2nd df?

Comment: I think around 50 rows in each df

Comment: can you show ten rows from each of your dataframes? `print(df.head(10).to_dict())` paste the output in your question

Comment: first df : {'team': {1: 'New England Patriots',
  2: 'Miami Dolphins',
  3: 'Buffalo Bills',
  4: 'New York Jets',
  6: 'Baltimore Ravens'},
 'W': {1: 11, 2: 7, 3: 6, 4: 4, 6: 10},
 'L': {1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 10, 4: 12, 6: 6},
 'Ratio': {1: 2.2,
  2: 0.7777777777777778,
  3: 0.6,
  4: 0.3333333333333333,
  6: 1.6666666666666667}}

Comment: second df : {'Metropolitan area': {0: 'New York City',
  1: 'Los Angeles',
  2: 'San Francisco Bay Area',
  3: 'Chicago',
  4: 'Dallas–Fort Worth'},
 'NFL': {0: 'GiantsJets',
  1: 'RamsChargers',
  2: '49ersRaiders',
  3: 'Bears',
  4: 'Cowboys'}}

Answer (score 0):

I am using your `df1`, `df2` as an example. First we need to create a column which is the last word in the team name. For df1 it is easy as can split on whitespace. For `df2` we split on capital letters, keeping the split letter in the list, and then combine the last two elements:

```
df1['token'] = df1['team'].str.split().apply(lambda l:l[-1])
df2['token'] = df2['NFL'].str.split('([A-Z])').apply(lambda l:l[-2]+l[-1])
```

eg we get for df2:

```
    Metropolitan area       NFL           token
--  ----------------------  ------------  --------
 0  New York City           GiantsJets    Jets
 1  Los Angeles             RamsChargers  Chargers
 2  San Francisco Bay Area  49ersRaiders  Raiders
 3  Chicago                 Bears         Bears
 4  Dallas–Fort Worth       Cowboys       Cowboys
```

Now we can merge on `token`:

```
df1.merge(df2,on='token',how='left')
```

the result not super-interesting as there is only one match but hopefully will work on your full dfs:

```
    team                    W    L     Ratio  token     Metropolitan area    NFL
--  --------------------  ---  ---  --------  --------  -------------------  ----------
 0  New England Patriots   11    5  2.2       Patriots  nan                  nan
 1  Miami Dolphins          7    9  0.777778  Dolphins  nan                  nan
 2  Buffalo Bills           6   10  0.6       Bills     nan                  nan
 3  New York Jets           4   12  0.333333  Jets      New York City        GiantsJets
 4  Baltimore Ravens       10    6  1.66667   Ravens    nan                  nan
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was insisting on doing it in one command while doing it in multiple steps like you did is quite simple

Comment: The syntax for splitting  on capital letters isn't working for me :)

Comment: does this work: `import re
re.split('([A-Z])','GiantsJets')`

Comment: what version of Pandas are you using

Comment: I'm using Pandas 1.1.4

Comment: Instead of `df2['token'] = df2['NFL'].str.split('([A-Z])').apply(lambda l:l[-2]+l[-1])` we could also do : `df2['token'] = df2['NFL'].apply(lambda z: re.findall('[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*$', z)[0])`